# How to serve HTTPS data on an AWS elastic beanstalk instance

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, openssl, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, vercel

I have an **elastic beanstalk instance** in which I have deployed my **spring-boot application**. By default elastic beanstalk gives you a URL for your environment over http.

While this works fine this has led to a lot of problems for me. I have the frontend **(my react application)** deployed on `Vercel`. I want my frontend app to get data from my elastic beanstalk app. Problem is the url is in http. On the console I get an error like this

**Mixed Content: The page at '' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource ''. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.**

which renders the app useless basically.

After hours of google I found out that I have to request the data over https because my vercel app is over https*`(I might be very wrong here)`* I've tried some solutions to get my elastic beanstalk app to serve the data on https to no avail.

Here is what I've tried

1. I created a self signed ssl certificate using openssl and uploaded
   it to AWS via the AWS cli. I then went to my applications load
   balancer settings and added the ssl certificate . (This did not
   work, I cried)
   [image: AWS Load balancer settings]
2. I used keytool to create yet another ssl certificate and added it to my
   resources folder and the corresponding settings in the
   application.settings file. I repackaged the jar file and redeployed
   it to AWS.(Still didn't work. *Didn't cry this time though. I was
   out of tears*)

***Question*** **How do I serve the data from my spring-boot app to my Vercel react app over https? Or any other method. Just anything that will work.**

If one thing is clear from all that long nonsense I've told you up there is I don't know wtf I'm doing. Just following a bunch of tutorials which for all I know keep destroying my app and your time even more.

Now my app is broken and now I cant even load the static assets on the elastic beanstalk URL because I'm getting another error

**400 Bad Request
The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port**

I know that question is really long and maybe even wrong. **Please help**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So once you have the SSL certificate ready this what you need to do in the AWS Elastic beanstalk to serve your application for https

Add a new listener to for port: 443  and select HTTPS

[image]

After this incase you are facing any certificate error while browsing the page, ensure that the URL mentioned in the certificate is matching the URL in browser

Comment: so i will then have two listener ports. the default and the new one?

Comment: if you want your site to be available over http & https should have ports at 80 and 443